# Извлечение информации из списка

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть список, в который я вывожу информацию из бд. Подскажите, как извлекать данные из списка при клике на элемент? Адаптер кастомный.

Comment: Вы можете добавить код воспользовавшись [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/667790/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у Вас есть БД, то можно вытащить из неё данные в виде **HashMap**.

Допустим, у БД есть столбцы _**Id, PRODUCTNAME,
            COAST, INCOME**

(Вы же можете просто поменять названия этих столбцов на свои в массиве строк, которые подаются как аргументы метода `query`. Ну и так же поменять обобщение у HashMap`а на те типы, которые используете Вы)

И вытащить их из БД можно, например, так:

```
 public HashMap<Long, String> getHashMap(String exec) {
    HashMap<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME,
            COLUMN_COAST, COLUMN_INCOME}, null, null, null, null, null); // Здесь в массиве String`ов просто поменяйте столбцы
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // Как пример
            long value = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(exec));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME));
            map.put(value, name);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return map;
}
```

И потом, прикрепив обработчик событий к ListView, вытаскивать их из HashMap по индексу:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Вытаскиваем данные из коллекции по текущей позиции элемента ListView
             ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: а зачем нужно помещать данные в HashMap, делать еще один запрос в БД и тратить ресурс устройства на ненужные операции, почему нельзя получить непосредственно Cursor в onItemClick() методом getItem() адаптера и работать  с ним.